# Using lambda function as a compare for a std::map

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, lambda

In VS2015 why can I do this

```
typedef std::pair<std::set<std::string>::const_iterator,std::set<std::string>::const_iterator> paircmpiter;
struct PairCmp {
    bool operator()(const paircmpiter& lhs, const paircmpiter& rhs) const {
        return (*lhs.first + *lhs.second) < (*rhs.first + *rhs.second);
    }
};
std::map <paircmpiter,std::vector<std::pair<std::set<std::string>::const_iterator, int>>, PairCmp> markov;
```

but not this

```
auto paircmp = [](const paircmpiter& lhs, const paircmpiter& rhs) {
    return (*lhs.first + *lhs.second) < (*rhs.first + *rhs.second);
};
std::map <paircmpiter,std::vector<std::pair<std::set<std::string>::const_iterator, int>>, decltype(paircmp)> markov;
```

I would have expected the `decltype` would allow me to use lambda functions as a comparison.

How do I make it work using the lambda syntax?

Comment: `std::map <paircmpiter,std::vector<std::pair<std::set<std::string>::const_iterator, int>>, decltype(paircmp)> markov(paircmp);`

Comment: Perfect thank you. Can you put as answer so I can vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a compilation error because [closure objects created by lambda expressions are not default-constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#ClosureType::ClosureType.28.29). But they are copy-constructible.

To fix, you need to pass the closure object into [`std::map` constructor that takes a `Compare` object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map):

```
std::map<
    paircmpiter,
    std::vector<std::pair<std::set<std::string>::const_iterator, int> >,
    decltype(paircmp)
    > markov{paircmp}; // <--- here
```